# Expectation of discrete joint random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with joint probability mass function,
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}.1&&x=-1,y=1\\.3&&x=-1, y=-1\\.2&&x=1,y=1\\.4&&x=1,y=-1\end{cases}$$

1. Compute $f(y) = \mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$.
2. Compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$ using the marginal pmf and then using the the law of iterated expectation. Do the results agree?

For 1), I did
$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=\begin{cases}0.333 &&y=1 \\0.143 && y=-1\end{cases}$$

But I am not sure why the pmf of y is found by calculting the expectation of X.

For 2), for calculating using marginal pmf, I did
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{x}xp(x)=(1)(0.6)+(-1)(0.4)=0.2$$

and for calculating by iterated expression, I did the same thing in 2) and summed up the expectations.

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X|Y=1]+\mathbb{E}[X|Y=-1]\\=[(-1)(\frac{0.1}{0.3})+(1)(\frac{0.2}{0.3})]+[(-1)(\frac{0.3}{0.7})+(1)(\frac{0.4}{0.7})]\\=0.476$$

But I am confused why the results do not agree and what went wrong in the two approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X|Y=1]\ \color{red}{\text{Pr}(Y=1)}+\mathbb{E}[X|Y=-1]\ \color{red}{\text{Pr}(Y=-1)}=0.2$$

Comment: Do you know what the second question means by $f(y) = \mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$ and why the pmf of y is equal to the conditional expectation?

Comment: I think this is some typo or mistake... doesn't make sense for me. It is not true that $f(y)=E(X|Y=y)$. Perhaps the correct text is "Compute $f(y)$ **and** $E(X|Y=y)$. That will be consistent with what is asked in the other question.